# Unexpected Symbol in R

Tags: r

Trying to make an allele frequency sample and having trouble with unexpected symbols. Any help is appreciated! Code below.

```
for (alleles.amount in 1:20) (event = sample(c('red', 'red'), 20, F, 
prob=c(0.75, 0.25)) white.count = c(white.count, sum(event == "white")))
```

Comment: Please use `{}`

Comment: As-in, `for ()` **`{`** `...` **`}`**